# Google App Engine for private usage?

Tags: google-app-engine

Is it possible to create a webapp on Google App Engine which can only be accessed by a single user? I'm thinking of a simple task management app for private usage.

Yes, I've already looked this up on the GAE docs, but I don't really understand what their domain based authentication system means.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Of course. Just do

```
if(user.email() == myemail)
```

once the User object has been created.

Comment: The "login: admin" option posted by Peter is a better solution. You don't have to worry about making sure all code paths do the check, and if you ever want to add a friend (or a cronjob, or task queue) you don't have to go modifying code :-)

Answer (score 15):

If by "single user" you mean only **you** will ever use the app, the simplest option is to configure the application to do the authentication for you.  In python this would be done using the app.yaml file, as shown [here](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig.html#Requiring_Login_or_Administrator_Status).  This way you can lock down a number of urls all at the same time.  Using the admin option would be appropriate if only you were to be allowed access, and the "required" option would work if you wanted others to be able to log in as well.

Sample of what the yaml would like:

```
handlers:

- url: /profile/.*
  script: user_profile.py
  login: required

- url: /admin/.*
  script: admin.py
  login: admin

- url: /.*
  script: welcome.py
```

Comment: is there an equivalent of this in the java world?

Answer (score 3):

"domain based authentication," once set up, causes the Web app to ask the user for a name and password. Without the proper credentials, he doesn't get access.

So this answers your question, and in the positive.